# Carousel - frame - contentSize

Tags: xcode, rápido

Tengo un ScrollView que lo utilizo para mostrar un carousel horizontal el problema que tengo es que en algunas resoluciones tiene problemas de que cuando avanzo se queda corrido para la derecha, pero no pasa en todas las resoluciones solo en algunas especificas,

muestro código que implementa ese add

```
@IBOutlet var carousel: UIScrollView!{
        didSet{
            carousel.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [Slide]) {
        
        let widthFrameCarousel = carousel.frame.width
        
        carousel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthFrameCarousel, height: carousel.frame.height)
        carousel.contentSize = CGSize(width: widthFrameCarousel * CGFloat(slides.count), height: 0)
        carousel.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: widthFrameCarousel * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: widthFrameCarousel, height: carousel.frame.height)

            carousel.addSubview(slides[i])
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

seteando con

```
let widthFrameCarousel = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

ya se fixea en los diferentes dispositivos